# How to make app still run when the hikaridatasource bean cannot be created due to some external datasource problem?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

when there will be an issue with the external database for a live webapp and bean won't be able to get instantiated when retried again by the application then app goes down how can we fix this problem?

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource(){
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-test"); 
    hikariConfig.setUsername("root");
    hikariConfig.setPassword("admin");

    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");

    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will probably throw an exception if the datasource is down. Wrap it into try/catch like so:

```
try {
   <your code goes here>
} catch (Exception e) {
   return null;
}
```

But code calling for a datasource will have to accept the result may be null rather than throwing NullPointerExceptions.